# How to reinstall Ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04, reinstall

I have dual booted my system Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. Ubuntu 16.04 is installed on a different partition of my disk. I want to reinstall the same Ubuntu in the same partition. I want to have only Ubuntu 16.04 on my system not its data that I have stored in it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the standard install instructions, doing the exact same thing you did when you initially installed Ubuntu. Select your existing Ubuntu as your install location and select "erase and install ubuntu".